# Windows Service will not start as Local User

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

**EDIT 2:** I now believe this is an issue with the machine I'm attempting to run the service on. I tried moving the service to a different machine that is setup similarly and the service was able to start successfully even as a Local User. Now I just need to figure out what's different between the two machines...

---

I have a Windows Service project (written in VB.net) that is installed and configured with a Startup Type of Automatic and the Log On As set to a Local User account. This service will start when the computer first starts up. However, if I stop the service and try to start it again, I get "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." immediately. However, if I change the Log On As to "Local System account" then the service will start.

Summary:

- Service will run as Local User when computer first starts
- Service will not run as Local User if started manually
- Service will run as Local System when computer first starts
- Service will run as Local System if started manually

I have read that Error 1053 is caused by the OnStart method not returning quickly enough. The fact that the service has started previously, and that I get the error message immediately, leads me to believe a timeout is not what's going on. To verify this, I created a completely new Windows Service Project and without changing anything I built and installed it. I get the same behavior.

I am at a loss as to what's happening. As far as I can tell, the Local User has all of the correct privileges to run a service (as is evident by the fact that it will start with those credentials when it the computer is first starting up), and the OnStart method isn't actually timing out (as is evident by the completely blank dumb service exhibiting the same behavior).

Any ideas as to what's preventing the service from starting, or where I can look for better error messages (I have looked in the Application Event Log, but nothing shows up there)?

**EDIT:**
Here is the code from the dumb service I created (using the EventLogger from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15291/Error-and-Event-Logging-in-VB-NET) as a module).

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    ' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
    ' in motion so your service can do its work.
    EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("On Start")
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
    ' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("On Stop")
End Sub
```

And the Main method of the same project.

```
' The main entry point for the process
<MTAThread()> _
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Shared Sub Main()
    EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Starting Main Method")
    Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1}

    System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    EventLogger.WriteToEventLog("Leaving Main Method")
End Sub
```

When I try to run the Service as the Local User, none of the messages show in the Event Log and I get Error 1053. When I run the Service as the Local System, the messages show in the Event Log.

The reason I need to run the actual service as the Local User is so that it can access a network share. I am currently looking into using Windows User Impersonation, but I still think I should be able to start a simple service as a Local User.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15291/Error-and-Event-Logging-in-VB-NET) to create an event logger. Then wrap your code in each sub in a try/catch b/c most likely something is happening in your OnStart sub that is preventing the service from starting. Post some sample code of your onstart, onstop, and/or your service main subs and clarify why you need to use the local user vs the local system.

Comment: The original program creates and starts a FileSystemWatcher in the OnStart method. However, I am also getting the same behavior in a Windows Service project that is completely blank. I do not think it's getting to the OnStart method, but I will add event logger calls and update my question.